# How to fix NameError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm tryting too put two windows as panel A and panelB but i'm getting following error

> if PanelA is None or PanelB if None: NameError: name 'panelA' is not
>   defined

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2

def select_image():
        global panelA, panelB
        path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if len(path) > 0:
                image = cv2.imread(path)
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image = Image.fromarray(image)
                edged = Image.fromarray(edged)
                image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
                edged = ImageTk.PhotoImage(edged)    
        if panelA is None or panelB is None:
                panelA = Label(image=image)
                panelA.image = image
                panelA.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)
                panelB = Label(image=edged)
                panelB.image = edged
                panelB.pack(side="right", padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
                panelA.configure(image=image)
                panelB.configure(image=edged)
                panelA.image = image
                panelB.image = edged
root = Tk()
panelA = None
panelB = None

btn = Button(root, text="Select an image", command=select_image)
btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx="10", pady="10")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This question is not answerable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You define global variable but you also need to initialize them if you want to compare them in an if statement :

```
global panelA, panelB
panelA, panelB = None, None
```

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your indentation.and panelA, panelB =''